# Screensaver start time always set to 20 minutes

Tags: mojave, screensaver

UPDATE: After observing this for a day or two, I can see that the idleTime is set to 5 minutes within System Preferences while `defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver idleTime` still returns `1200`.

---

The options to change the delay time within System Preferences is grayed out so I couldn't change it.

So I tried setting it with `defaults`.

```
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver idleTime -int 300
```

After running that command, I'll get this.

```
$ defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver idleTime
300
```

However, once I go back to the screen saver settings in System Preferences, the delay goes back to 20 minutes and I get this.

```
$ defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver idleTime
1200
```

The global default is set to 300.

```
$ defaults read com.apple.screensaver idleTime
300
```

I've also tried deleting the whole `com.apple.screensaver` domain and then go back to screen saver section in System Preferences, and I see 20 minutes and 1200 again.

I have a profiles in place where the screen saver idleTime is set to 300 but I have no idea why it's getting set to 1200.

This is on Mojave 10.14.1 (18B75).

Comment: Is your Mac managed by an organization? (i.e. your work place or similar)

Comment: Not sure but very likely as I don't see it happening when I turn off my wifi.

Comment: How can you not know if your Mac is managed? - Where have you got it from?

Comment: From my colleague. Even the person who handed it over to me didn't know what's going on and that's beyond me.

Comment: @jksoegaard so when Mac is managed by the organization it's impossible to set anything else rather than 20 minutes (or whatever is preset by admin profile)?

Comment: @OlehZiniak If the Mac is managed, and they have forced a setting of 20 minutes, then no - it is not immediately possible to set another value. However, it is not the case that just because it is managed, it is also by definition forced to 20 minutes (i.e. this is something the organization must have set themselves).

Comment: Guys, Mac is no longer managed. There is no Profile, nor MDM, etc. Something keeps reverting my settings - expected answer is not "Mac is managed - you can do nothing".